# How to add normal vehicle rather than intelligent connect vehicle in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

How to add normal vehicle rather than intelligent connect vehicle in Veins?
In Veins5.1, it seems like every vehicle should be a node and send message with each other. How can I add normal vehicles which will not communicate with other vehicles in simulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want some random vehicles to be "dumb" vehicles, you can set the [`penetrationRate` parameter](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.ned#L76) of `TraCIScenarioManager` to a value smaller than its default, `1.0`. If you set this value to, e.g., `0.1`, only 10% of your vehicles will be "intelligent" vehicles. The remaining 90% will not even be simulated in OMNeT++.

If you are looking for more control over which vehicles are "dumb" and which vehicles are "intelligent", I would suggest using different OMNeT++ module types for "dumb" and for "intelligent" vehicles. In addition to the standard `Car.ned` module you could, for example, provide an alternative `DumbCar.ned` which cannot communicate at all. You can then use the `TraCIScenarioManager` [parameter `moduleType`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.ned#L51) to configure which SUMO vehicle types are mapped onto which OMNeT++ module types. More documentation on how to use this parameter is [contained in the source code](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L133).